# ALSA Callback When New Card/Device is Added

Tags: linux, callback, alsa

I'm working with the ALSA C API, and I need to be able to detect when a card is plugged in (example: adding a USB device with sound capabilities). I know that you can subscribe to events for a particular card, but I want to generically subscribe saying "When a new card is added, tell me."

Is this possible with the ALSA API? Or do I just need to launch a thread and continuously query for changes.

Comment: This is not part of the ALSA API. You have to listen to udev events.

Comment: Thanks CL!
Feel free to create an answer and I'll mark it correct. :)